# Ajax autocomplete with List of object in .Net not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to get all the users that the name contains some string like with ajax autocomplete but without result
here is my code client JS

```
$("#<%= UserName.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                 //  autoFocus: true,
                 minLength: 1,
                 delay: 1000,
                 source: function (request, response) {
                     $.ajax({
                         url: "default.aspx/AjaxGetUsers",
                         type: "POST",
                         dataType: "json",
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                         data: "{ 'nameToSearch' : '" + $("#<%=UserName.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
                       //  dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },

                         success: function (data) {
                             response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                 return {
                                     label: item.name,
                                     value: item.id
                                 }
                             }))
                             //debugger;
                         },
                         error: function (result) {
                             alert("Error");
                         }
                     });
                 },
                 focus: function (event, ui) {
                     $("#<%= UserName.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.name);
                     return false;
                 },

                 select: function (event, ui) {
                     $("#<%= UserName.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.name);
                     $("#<%= UserID.ClientID %>").val(ui.item.id);

                     return false;
                 }
             })
             .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                     return $("<li>")
                       .append("<a>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.id + "</a>")
                       .appendTo(ul);
                 };
```

AJax request is processing very well  with success 200 Ok. my code behind is returning a list of object.

```
{"d":[
{"__type":"School.UserForAutoComplete",
"name":"Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich","id":"4ff81581-e1ba-42b5-a8d8-d25ca509286f"},     
{"__type":"School.UserForAutoComplete",
"name":"Brown John Vasya","id":"695ef73c-3e1e-4877-bdd7-dfe166c5f155"}]}
```

Please someone detect what is wrong with my code ?
I tried everything in google result an here, without result. must of material is about list of string not about array of object.

Comment: Try iterating `data.d` in your success callback.

Comment: Thank for your answer. but i didn't understand very well what you mean here. do you mean through $.each? i tried this one already. any example please?

Comment: `$.map(data.d, ...` If that doesn't work, try adding `console.log()` statements and verifying that the returned object is what you expect.